# What does TTK mean?

Tags: terminology, wildstar

When playing Wildstar I read a lot about TTK on the forums. I assume it has something to do with DPS but what does it actually stand for?

Comment: This applies to nearly all games as well. FPS games use TTK or STK(Shots to Kill), so don't think this term only applies to wildstar ;)

Comment: @Rapitor: I didn't know that. Thanks :) I'm more used to DPS (Damage Per Second) and DoT (Damage over Time) from playing WoW. Wildstar was just the first time I came across TTK but it is good to know that TTK is more common than I thought. Amazing how many different terms exist describing the same thing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From what I have been reading up on multiple forums, your assumption is correct as it is related to DPS. TTK stands for Time To Kill - as in how long it takes for you to kill the enemy player/NPC.

Comment: That makes sense. So obvious now when I see it but thinking in relation to damage I just couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Haha, I couldn't make the connection myself until I started going through various gaming boards.